# Get max of count() function on pandas groupby objects

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

#### Problem

Using pandas, I need to get back the row with the max count for each groupby object.

#### Dataset

I have a dataframe called "matches" that looks like this:

`FeatureID    gene  pos
0        1_1_1  KRAS_1    6
1        1_1_1  KRAS_2    8
2        1_1_1  KRAS_3   11
3        1_1_1  NRAS_1    3
4        1_1_1  NRAS_2   11
5        1_1_1  NRAS_3   84
6       1_1_10  KRAS_1    4
7       1_1_10  KRAS_2    3
8       1_1_10  KRAS_3   14
9       1_1_10  NRAS_1    4
10      1_1_10  NRAS_2    6
11      1_1_10  NRAS_3   83`

#### What I've tried

I need to group together the dataframe by FeatureID and then get the count of positions in each group:

```
matches.groupby(["FeatureID", "gene"]).count()
```

Which results in:

`FeatureID gene
1_1_1     KRAS_1    6
          KRAS_2    8
          KRAS_3   11
          NRAS_1    3
          NRAS_2   11
          NRAS_3   84
1_1_10    KRAS_1    4
          KRAS_2    3
          KRAS_3   14
          NRAS_1    4
          NRAS_2    6`

#### Desired output:

I need to get back the row in each groupby object that contains the highest count, but I cannot figure out how to do that.

`FeatureID gene count
1_1_1 NRAS_3   84
1_1_10 KRAS_3   14`

#### Solution

The following line gives me back the gene with the max value for each groupby group:

```
matches.groupby(["FeatureID", "gene"]).count().sort_values("pos").groupby(level=0).tail(1)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do with `max` on `level=0`

```
matches.groupby(["FeatureID", "gene"]).count().max(level=0)
```

If keep both level

```
df.groupby(["FeatureID", "gene"]).count().sort_values().groupby(level=0).tail(1)
```

Comment: Gah! I didn't realize there was a "level" argument on max. Thanks! How do I retain the info about which gene had the max count?

Comment: This doesn't work on large data sets, anything else possible ?

Comment: you can pass max as an argument in the group by: df.groupby(["FeatureID", "gene"]).agg(['max']).